# Eloquent Relation With 2 Condition Join

Tags: mysql, laravel

Hello guys i got trouble with eloquent relations

I got 2 Table

### Table: itemprices

> **Columns:**
>    weaponid,
>    type,
>    price

and:

### Table: caseitems

> **Columns:**
>    id,
>    caseid,
>    weaponid
>   typeid

How can i convert this query to eloquent relation or query builder. I can do it with 1 condition but not 2 conditions :(

```
SELECT * FROM caseitems 
JOIN itemprices ON caseitems.weaponid = itemprices.weaponid 
     AND  caseitems.typeid = itemprices.type
```

Comment: Add your attempted code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will work fine:

```
$join = caseitems::join('itemprices','caseitems.weaponid','=','itemprices.weaponid')=>where('caseitems.type.id','=','itemprice.type';)
```

Comment: Defining relationship between 'caseitems' and 'itemprices' table will make things easier and better.

Comment: Did u mean relations in mysql or in eloquent? And can you give me a example :)

Comment: I meant relationship in eloquent. You can refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships for more about relationships.